# Do I need create tables manually in Google BigQuery to view the raw event data from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I had created a android App with Google Firebase supported and linked to the BigQuery yesterday.

Today I've seen the event report on the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), but after I clicked the **View** button in the *Event* page like the image below

[image]

I saw none table in the BigQuery page and got a warning saying the project's table is dismissing.

I wonder if I need do something, like creating some table manually or calling some Firebase or BigQuery APIs in my app. But I've looked up [the official document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) which saying

> Once an app is linked to BigQuery, a corresponding dataset will be
>   created in the associated BigQuery project upon the first daily export
>   of events. Each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a
>   new table in the associated dataset.

It seems I need do nothing. So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After you link your Firebase app to BigQuery, the next day, your events will flow from Firebase to BigQuery and this will automatically create the BigQuery dataset and its first daily table.  Keep in mind that if your app is not logging any events, then no events will be sent to BigQuery. And the dataset will not be created until some events have been logged after the linkage.

Comment: This is not happening to me. It's been 5 days and the datasets are not created. This is a web firebase app, Is that a problem?

Comment: @BernalCarlos  Did you find solution for the same? I am also waiting for the events to show up in the big query from 3 days.

Comment: @Imran Yes. I put a ticket with google an this was their answer.

Comment: Please try the following troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue:

Add firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com as an Editor on the project from the GCP console. Wait for at least 24 hours, and check for the data.
If the above doesn't work, then try adding a native mobile application (Android/iOS) in your project. Once that's done, unlink and relink Firebase and BigQuery. Wait for some time for the datasets to appear.

Comment: Adding firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com as an Editor on the project from the GCP console, solved the problem for me

Comment: @BernalCarlos I am doing this in iOS. Before that Android team has already done it and their data was syncing properly. When I did in iOS, no new tables are getting created for iOS but the old tables from the Android team is visible. Also, I did Add the firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com as you suggested but still waiting for the new tables in big query.

Comment: unlinking and linking big-query again to the project solved the problem for me immediately without having to wait after re-linking

Comment: Confirm: Adding firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com and crashlytics-exporter@crashlytics-bigquery-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com users solve this issue.